# PyExc_ValueError and Firefox extension

Tags: python, firefox-addon, xpcom, pycrypto

I'm developing a firefox addon which is depended on Python (which means that the user must install PyXpcomExt on his firefox). On the other hand I used PyCrypto lib (based on python) for encryption purposes.

So when firefox is loaded I have registered path to this library. However when the extension is run I get the following error:

File "/home/.../.mozilla/firefox/qvpgc3wq.default/extensions/..../pylib/mycryptoclass.py", line 4, in 
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES

ImportError: /home/.../.mozilla/firefox/qvpgc3wq.default/extensions/.../platform/Linux_x86-gcc3/pylib/Crypto/Cipher/AES.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_ValueError

I also tried:

import Crypto
from Crypto import Cipher

No error is thrown!

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you linking against the static or the dynamic Python library?

Answer (score 0):

AES.so has not been linked against the Python dynamic library. It's finding other symbols it needs in the process's symbol table, but it can't find that one and doesn't know where it is.

Comment: Link AES.so against the Python dynamic library when building.